# how to upload image with blob data type in database and display from database to view using laravel? i am try something like this

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

i try some thing like this as below given code. here i m try to upload an image with longblob datatype into database using laravel and mysql (heidiSQL). is this right way or not if not then what is the right way to solve this query? please... help me to solve this..... 
this is my image upload view

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="NewClientBox">
        <div class="step-1">
        <hr>
            <h2 style="width: 70%; text-align: center;"><p>Step 1</p></h2>
        <hr>
        <h4>Save Image</h4>

        <form id="clientForm" method="post" target="ifr" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{$path}}/admin-saveImage" onsubmit="return loadClients()">


            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" placeholder="Choose Client Image"name="image">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-1"><label></label></div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" class="form-control btn-success btn-save-client" value="Upload Image">
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>
        <iframe id="ifr" name="ifr" style="width: 1px; height: 1px;visibility: hidden;"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my show image view

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="NewClientBox">
        <div class="step-1">
        <hr>
        <h4>Show Image</h4>
        @foreach($image as $img)
        <img src="{{$img->image}}">
        @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this my controller

```
 public function Image(){
        return View::make('admin.imageUpload');
    }

    public function saveImage(){
        $image = new Image();
        $img = Input::file('image');
        $image->image=$img;
        $image->created_at = date("Y-m-d");
        $image->save();
    }

    public function showImage(){
        $image=Image::all();
        return View::make('admin.imageShow')->with('image',$image);
    }
```

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: yes it is :   Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/xampp/tmp/phpFA22.tmp

Answer (score 0):

The below code just save the local temp route for the image. Instead, you need to save the image content into the database.

```
$img = Input::file('image');
```

Does `{{$path}}/admin-saveImage` route to the `saveImage()`? If it does, you should add a parameter (Request `$request`) into it. Try to dump out the `$request` to see if it contain image content and save that into DB.